# text-overflow:elipsis in vertical-text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a text with two attributes that I don't know if they are compatible.
1.- It must be vertical.
2.- If it is too big for the content, you must put an ellipsis.

I have the text already vertical, but I think that the ellipsis does not work there

```css
.cell{
    display: inline-flex;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    height: 100px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.area .rating{
    writing-mode:vertical-rl;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    align-items: left;
    justify-content: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;    
}
```

```html
<div class="cell area" id="be-area-info">
   <div class="rowTable">
    <div class="cell rating">Examen alcsf sdf asd</div>
    <div class="cell rating">20</div>
    <div class="cell rating">20</div>
    <div class="cell rating">20</div>
    <div class="cell rating">20</div>
    <div class="cell rating"><i class="fad fa-layer-plus"></i></div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

[image]

I need the Inline-flex to be maintained, because inline-block leaves spaces between the divs

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve the two goals. I updated your styles.

```css
.cell {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    height: 100px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.area .rating {
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="cell area" id="be-area-info">
  <div class="rowTable">
    <div class="cell rating">Examen alcsf sdf asd</div>
    <div class="cell rating">20</div>
    <div class="cell rating">20</div>
    <div class="cell rating">20</div>
    <div class="cell rating">20</div>
    <div class="cell rating"><i class="fad fa-layer-plus"></i></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need it to stay as it is, the only thing I want to add is that the text be cut off and add **ellipsis**, 
I need to keep the **inline-flex**